# How to make overflow visible for a section with a set height?

Tags: html, css

I have a section with a set height of 700px. Inside this section is a container, due to the contents inside the container the height exceeds 700px and the overflow is shown which is the desired effect. However, when I add another section below this one, the contents of the new section overlaps the overflown piece of the container.

```
<section class="info">
    <div class="container">
        <!--Some Content-->
    </div>
</section>
<section class="text">
    <!--Some Content-->
</section>
```

I've tried giving the container class a z-index of 1, and also giving the info section an overflow visible and a z-index of 1, but nothing seems to work.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/KevinM818/pen/EoybqZ

Comment: You should post an actual working demo so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/KevinM818/pen/EoybqZ

Comment: Just made a codepen of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

z-index will only work on an element which is positioned as `absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`. You can extract the lightblue box and set it to `position: absolute;`, then set the `z-index` on both `bg` div and `container` div. Or you can set `z-index: -1;" to the`bg`div and remove`position`and`z-index`from the`container` div.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.info {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  height: 700px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.info .container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: grey;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text {
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <!--Some Content-->
  </div>
</section>
<section class="text">
  <!--Some Content-->
  <h1>How do I stop this green from overlapping the grey container?</h1>
</section>
```

Adjusted:
I saw your comments on the other post. If you want the gray box overlaps on the green box, you can simply add `position: relative;` to `info` div in your original code.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
}

.info {
  height: 700px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.info .container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: grey;
}

.text {
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <div class="container">
    <!--Some Content-->
  </div>
</section>
<section class="text">
  <!--Some Content-->
  <h1>How do I stop this green from overlapping the grey container?</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: @Kevin Mangal I added the second code snippet if you want the gray box overlaps on the green box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the green text to be covered, then you'll have to allow `section.info` to be taller than `700px`.

Give `section.text` absolute positioning at `top=700px`, remove the `height` constraint on `section.info` and give it a higher `z-index`, and it should work out.

Adjusted codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJzJzE

Comment: The goal of the design is to have the container overlapping into the next section. If I remove the height constraint in section.info then it will just auto fit to the height of the container.

Comment: Take a look at the codepen I posted. I'm assuming this is what you mean by "overlapping into the next section" (i.e. the green text is covered by the grey). I've floated both sections and given them absolute positioning. If that's not what you mean, then perhaps I'm not understanding the requirements properly?